# how to put all labels in bold with css

Tags: html, css, fonts, colors

how do I make all labels such as : first name, last name, etc in bold, by using header only? 
thank you

```
 <form>
                <fieldset class="set1">
                    <legend class="set1">Music Lover's Personal information</legend>
                    First Name
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" value=""><br><br>
                    Family Name
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" value=""><br><br>
                    Gender:
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<br><br>
                    What age category are you from?
```

Comment: What do you mean by "using header only"? What have you tried? Finally, since you mentioned labels in your question, why not actually use them?

Comment: I mean by not doing <b>first name</b> etc. But by doing that from the header only

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @DavidBenalal ! people who answer your questions may be happier if you apply  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would wrap each label in a `label` tag and then in CSS, with this code, you can get it:

```
form label {font-weight:bold}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are unable to change your HTML markup and actually use labels, or spans, or other tags to wrap your labels, then you'd have to do something like:

```
fieldset { font-weight: bold; }
fieldset * { font-weight: normal; }
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all , please use proper HTML for your form by defining labels:

**HTML**

```
<label for="firstname">First Name</label>
```

**CSS:**

```
form label{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Add any additional style to the css. You can use a class in your form if you have more than one form.